# Error whilst calling upon function in .mo file

Tags: stata

I have created an .ado file, which defines a function and is stored in a .mo file, created at the end of said .ado file.

This function is then called upon in a .do file, however it results in a conformability error (rc3200), although despite turning trace on to try to debug the process, the error only points to the function and not the specific point at which two matrices cannot conform and further, which two matrices they are specifically.

Is there a way of turning the trace on, to show the step-by-step operation of the function that is called upon by the .do file from the created .mo file?

Comment: Also posted and answered on Statalist at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1345540-viewing-trace-output-of-functions

Answer (score 1):

If `trace` cannot be made to provide you the debugging information you need, consider temporarily inserting

```
stata(`"display "<informative message>""')
```

throughout your function to help you locate where the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks William, I've added the above line with just one accent, however there is a "mismatched quotes r(3000)" error. Is the above syntax correct?

Edit: I think it should be: `stata(`"display "<informative message>""')'

Comment: Writing Stata syntax within sentences that includes left quotes is a pain because of their other meaning in Stack Overflow. Rather than fight with escape characters, just display the syntax on its own line(s).

Comment: Of course, Nick. Thank you for taking care of the edit to my post - it now matches my intent.